# Automated way to recognize musical key given chords?

Tags: chords, key-signatures

Assuming I have access to the chords of a song, I 'know' (based on my own experience and training) what key the song is likely to be in. And for pop music, the recognition rate is easily above 95%. To be fair, for certain types of pop music the key is just the final chord of the song though.

Have there been attempts at deriving musical key from a list (ordered or unordered) of chords in the song? I'm looking for either a list of rules or (preferably) a computer program.

Initial thoughts:-

- If a song has lots of C, F, and G major chords, it's probably in C
- The first and/or last chord would have inordinate importance
- Differentiating between Am and C would be much harder than between C and D

Clarifications:-
 - Let's just assume 'simple' music, pop-ish, meant for acoustic guitar/simple piano playing.
 - The 'chords' that I'm thinking about here are boring old guitar chords (Cmaj7, D/F#, Gsus4) style

Comment: What do you do to "know" what key a song is in? Can you determine a key from a list of chords? How are you doing that? That would answer your own question.

Comment: Unordered? How is one going to do that without some idea of ordering and rhythmic priorities? If I use mostly major triads on F, C and G, I can tonicise F quite as easily as I can C (V/V - V - I). I can even end the piece on a C chord and make it seem like an unresolved ending on the dominant. So it will depend on the ordering (the progression), to be sure, but also on line and rhythm to make my key clear.

Comment: @Patrx2 - I've often wondered about the situation you suggest. If, with only C, F and G, but construed to be 'in F', I think most of the B notes would be B rather than Bb.So, what would the key sig. have to be? If it was for F, then most of the Bbs would end up cancelled, in which case it could be generally thought of as, well, it's pretty much in C, isn't it?     An example that comes to mind is Sweet Home  Alabama. In D or G? I've seen in written in both! And in C, with zero key sig...

Comment: @Tim, the B notes are where line and rhythm come in. Imagine the G chord falling on a relatively unstressed beat, then dwelling on C for a while, then bringing in F on a beat where you expect a cadence to end, _but imagine the F chord with a stressed B♭ appoggiatura_. The B♭ is a linear artifact, a nonharmonic tone, but it has a harmonically disambiguating effect. Without the support of line and rhythm, a small number of chords can be extremely ambiguous, but, with the support of these elements, even a single chord can establish a tonality: see the Prelude to Das Rheingold.

Comment: @Patrx2 - or could it be argued that the C/F/G song is in F is actually in F Lydian? What about a key sig? Point taken completely re. positioning of chord in bar/phrase.

Comment: @Tim, it could be, or it could be taken that B♮ is just part of V of V, a substitute for ii, cycle-of-fifths stuff - that situation might remain ambiguous or it might be clarified perfectly by rhythm and line - but it remains that I could tonicise F using those chords. It's even (somewhat) conceivable that I could tonicise _G_ with those chords, with careful attention to order, rhythm and the nonharmonic notes in the lines - G with an extremely strong Mixolydian flavour. (Be Hellish difficult, mind you.)

Comment: @Patrx2 - o.k. Thanks. There are a some two chord songs I've played: mostly I-V, but one or two seem to come out as IV-I, which is just the sort of thing you mention. The theorist in me says they should all be I-V, and end on I, but it ain't necessarily so.

Comment: When you use the word "automated" I take it literally and expect you mean "using a computer algorithm." Do you actually mean something more like "formula" or "cheat sheet?"

Comment: Second question that could help determine an answer: why do you want to do this? What will you do after you label music with a key? In other words, who cares what the key is if you already have chord labels? There should be a reason why you want to know this. I could imagine it's for harmonic analysis, or notating sheet music, but what is your reason?

Comment: "Music and Probability" by David Temperley might be an interesting read.

Comment: Yes, read David Temperley!

Comment: @thrig Thanks so much for the David Temperley suggestion, will certainly give that a read soon.

And I'm interested in a computer algorithm, eventually, but a formula or cheat sheet will get me there within issue.

Comment: @Patrx2 Ordered is fine as well if it's necessary.

Comment: In case others haven't tried looking,Temperley has a lot of papers online. http://davidtemperley.com/papers/. My favorite is 'Melodic-Harmonic divorce in rock' which has some bearing on this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, because you limit your question to a simple pop context. But, I would suggest this:

- Always keep in mind a song can modulate. The whole song may be in one key, but you might also need to apply some "local" key changes to sections of a song.
- Caveat: when pop styles use minor harmony there is a tendency for the music to not be in a key in the standard music theory sense. It will tend to be either modal - like d dorian in "Riders on the Storm" - or minor pentatonic scale oriented - like in hard rock songs such as "Hair of the Dog." Identifying a modal tonality is more complicated so we won't try to do it here.
- The straight forward way to determine key is by finding the primary tonal triads: tonic, subdominant, dominant. In major keys this is simple: C, F, G or I, IV, V. In minor keys look for cm, fm, Gmaj or i, iv, V. You could find a chart listing all keys like [this](http://www.musictheoryacademy.com/understanding-music/primary-chords/).
- Keep in mind other chords are likely used even in a simple song. But for the purpose of identifying key you can disregard those chords, and focus on the primary triads. For example, in this common chord progression -  C a-min F G (I vi IV V) you can disregard the a minor, the C, F, G chords match the primary chords for C major.
- If a given song doesn't fit neatly into the steps above, you probably aren't dealing with simple songs, and will have to use more sophisticated methods. That's ok! Use a simple method when appropriate, switch to sophisticated analysis when needed.

Additional comments:

@Patrx2 and @Tim point out some good "gotchas." But, if you find such things in a particular song, it probably isn't the simple pop music your are focusing on and you won't be able to approach it with a simple formula/method.

You may find a lot of music that seems simple is not simple in terms of key/tonality. My simple outline will work well with a lot of Buddy Holly songs or 1960's doo-wop, etc. but it won't help much with many Beatles songs, and many, many other interesting songs.

Comment: ...and that last sentence sums up what is problematic about the venture. It's precisely when things get interesting that simple automation will be problematic, and even not-so-simple automation will be iffy. Hewing to the statistical mean is not very interesting; naming the key you're in is not very interesting; finding out how you got there is _very_ interesting, but usually requires more than enumerating chords.

Comment: I agree absolutely. Enumerating chords or notes which match a key is not enough. I hope my answer isn't misleading in this regard. I tried to give clear caveats to avoid that mistake.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer, but for clarification - it sounds like you're suggesting chord counting and assuming that the 3 most numerous chords are I, IV, and V? Simple enough to do, and I'll have to test it with some of the songs I want to use, but as already mentioned by others this will be quite brittle with anything beyond the simplest (and won't cover what I personally consider 'pop', though I understand that to be subjective)

Comment: Also, what would 'sophisticated analysis' look like? I'm skimming through "Music and Probability" now, which looks interesting except for the focus on melodic/note structure which is at odds with the 'based on chords' plan I have. The only relevant bit it seems to have is the 'relatedness' of keys.

Comment: The easiest way to reduce complexity for an algorithm is a scoring mechanism that favors the most common choices, maybe start with the list of most common and then eliminate them somehow. I expect Differential Diagnosis algorithms might be helpful here. Remember: When you hear hoofbeats, look for horses, not zebras

Comment: @Ng Oon-Ee, "And I Love Her" by the Beatles is a good example. Check this out: http://www.recmusicbeatles.com/public/files/awp/ailh.html. I'm not so much interested in what the analysis symbols look like, but that it becomes more of a discussion.

Comment: I think the main point of this lively discussion is the importance of knowing how to and when to apply various analysis tools. Identifying the primary triads is a useful tool. It will work for "Words of Love" by Buddy Holly. But, you can rely solely on this one tool.

Comment: Corollary point after reading that interesting short article by @MichaelCurtis - if all you're after is 'best guess' then chord counting would still have worked in that example (as is the case for me). Which brings me back to another point from Music and Probability, that its all about perception and it seems fairly simple for experienced musicians/composers to 'direct' perception, which leaves the 'right' answer fairly ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

sure there is.  same way ya do it manually.

relying on chords won't be as good as just using melody.

due to the chords often being dom7 and that minor7 being out of keysig.  kinda.

take the melody, see where it's 7 most popular notes are, boom - there's your keysig usually.

due to pop usually being in major, vocals and bass usually staying in keysig.

I've tried this out on a bunch of pop midi files and it usually works great.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in something based on chords, primarily because it's easier to obtain chords than melody notes generally (in numbers, of course, not referring to any specific tune/song).

Comment: using the notes of the chord will still work.  the 7 most popular notes will still outweigh the minor 7ths cuz the chords's main 3 will build up way faster than the dom7.